# MATLAB: Specify a fixed color for zero in imagesc

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have sets of 2D data that spread across negative value to positive value. When plotted using `imagesc` for different set of data, it'll be inconsistent to look at as the zero value is not always at a fixed color. Is it possible to fix a color for `0` value and then both negative and positive value to progress from there?

Thank you!

Comment: You are probably using a diverging colormap (I hope) for this, but to do wha you want, you will likely need to either crop the colormap or use `caxis` properly. Have a look

Comment: Yes, I am. `caxis` is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much! :)